# Trigonometric Integration with $\tan^3(x)$

Tags: calculus

I'd like to compute: $\int_0^{\pi/3}\tan^3(x)\;dx$.

I can't seem to find the step after splitting the original integral into $\tan^2(x) \cdot (1 - \sec^2(x))$.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It is $\tan x(1-\sec^2 x)=\tan x-\tan x\sec^2 x$. Now each part is reasonably straightforward.

Comment: @auburntiger1. What is the derivative of tanx?

Comment: I know the first part of the integral. Do I use a integration by parts for second part?

Comment: No, that was exactly my hint: Use a u-sub $tanx=t$ because it then becomes very easy, because the tangent is multiplied by its own derivative...

Answer (score 1):

$$\int\tan^3(x)\mathrm d x=\int(\tan(x)(1+\tan^2(x)))\mathrm d x-\int\tan(x)\mathrm d x.$$

If $u=\tan(x)$, then $\mathrm d u=(1+\tan^2(x))\mathrm d x$, and thus the first integral follow. You probably should be able to compute the seconde one.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
  \int \tan^3 x \, dx &= \int \tan x \, (\sec^2 x-1) \,dx \\
  &= \int \sec x \, (\tan x \sec x \, dx )-\int \tan x \, dx \\
  &= \int \tan x \, d(\sec x)-\int \frac{\sin x \, dx}{\cos x} \\
  &= \frac{\sec^2 x}{2}+\int \frac{d(\cos x)}{\cos x} \\
  &= \frac{\sec^2 x}{2}+\ln |\cos x|+C
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$1+\tan^2x=\sec^2x$$

Therefore the integral is $$\int \tan x(\sec^2x-1)dx=\frac 12\tan^2x-\ln|\sec x|+c$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi/3}\tan^3xdx=\int_0^{\pi/3}{\sin^3x\over\cos^3x}dx&=\int_1^{1/2}{c^2-1\over c^3}dc\quad\text{with }c=\cos x\\
&=\int_1^{1/2}\left({1\over c}-{1\over c^2}\right)dc\\
&=\left(\ln c+{1\over2c^2}\right)\Big|_1^{1/2}\\
&=(\ln(1/2)-\ln(1))+(2-(1/2))\\
&={3\over2}-\ln2
\end{align}$$